# Spring security oauth2: create user if not exists, provision user

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-security, oauth-2.0, spring-security-oauth2

Here is an excerpt from [spring oauth2 tutorial](https://spring.io/guides/tutorials/spring-boot-oauth2):

> How to Add a Local User Database
>
> Many applications need to hold data about their users locally, even if
>   authentication is delegated to an external provider. We don’t show the
>   code here, but it is easy to do in two steps.
>
> Choose a backend for your database, and set up some repositories (e.g.
>   using Spring Data) for a custom User object that suits your needs and
>   can be populated, fully or partially, from the external
>   authentication.
>
> Provision a User object for each unique user that logs in by
>   inspecting the repository in your /user endpoint. If there is already
>   a user with the identity of the current Principal, it can be updated,
>   otherwise created.
>
> Hint: add a field in the User object to link to a unique identifier in
>   the external provider (not the user’s name, but something that is
>   unique to the account in the external provider).

So, in the user controller we have the following code:

```
@RequestMapping("/user")
public Map<String, Object> user(Principal user) {
    Map<String, Object> map = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    // for a facebook the name is facebook id, not an actual name
    map.put("name", user.getName());
    map.put("roles", AuthorityUtils.authorityListToSet(((Authentication) user)
            .getAuthorities()));
    return map;
}
```

[Dave Syer(spring maintainer) suggests to](https://github.com/spring-guides/tut-spring-boot-oauth2/issues/8):

> Downcast the Principal to an Authentication (or possibly
>   OAuth2Authentication and grab the userAuthentication from that) and
>   then look in the details property. If your user was authenticated
>   using a UserInfoTokenServices you will see the Map returned from the
>   external provider's user info endpoint.

But for me that seems unnatural by two reasons:

1. Why should we do that in controller call...it smells.
2. Why should we do all that instanceof and casts..smells as well.

Wouldn't it be better to plugin the `OAuth2AuthenticationManager` instead: `org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.authentication.OAuth2AuthenticationManager`

```
public Authentication authenticate(Authentication authentication) throws AuthenticationException {
     // ...
    OAuth2Authentication auth = tokenServices.loadAuthentication(token);
    // ...
    auth.setDetails(authentication.getDetails());
    auth.setAuthenticated(true);
    // here we could've create our own Authentication object
    // to set as Principal with application specific info. 
    // Note: no casts are required since we know the actual auth type
    return auth;
}
```

What's the best way of creating a user after oauth2 dance completed?

Comment: Another downside of the suggested approach is that you have then no idea what should be the user's login - you can only generate it - to make matters worse changing the login afterwards may not be possible